# Unreal development kit scaleform error "Actionscript version mismatch"

Tags: actionscript-3, unreal-development-kit, scaleform

I'm getting an error through the gfxUI channel;

```
DevGFxUI: Failed loading SWF "/ package/UDKFrontend/udk_ime": ActionScript version mismatch
```

this causes the entire project to crash. I'm not sure what this means so I'd appreciate any sort of input in terms of what this means.

Comment: Sounds like it's looking for a .swf file (which is the extension for compiled Flash files). I'd check the path is correct, because the space between the / and packages (and the lack of the .swf at the end) is suspicious.